# What is the difference in load() and refresh() method of GenericXmlApplicationContext (in Spring framework-Java)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
ctx.load("classpath:app-context-xml.xml");
ctx.refresh();
```

Why do we need to refresh() the context after loading? What is the difference in both methods.
And why is there exception when you call refresh() twice...?

What exactly be done in load() and refresh() methods. What happens when i call load() on context and what happens when i call refresh() on context?

Please answer. Thanks.

Comment: My question is what exactly be done in load() and refresh() methods. What happens when i call load() on context and what happens when i call refresh() on context?

Answer (score 0):

The load() method only loads bean definitions from resource (e.g. XML file) without actual creation of the beans while refresh() does the latter.
Whether load() or refresh() call are explicitly needed or not depends on how application context is created. Calling either or methods manually is required when application context creation is splitted into several steps, so you call first no-args constructor, then load configuration and finally call refresh(). However if constructor is used with an argument as XML configuration file or java class (which contains annotated configuration - in case when AnnotationConfigApplicationContext is used) then configuration loading (e.g. using load() call) and refresh() call are made inside that constructor so no additional load() and refresh() calls are necessary.

NB. refresh() could be called only once per application context instance.
GenericApplicationContext even contains code which throws IllegalStateException explicitly if refresh() called twice:

```
    protected final void refreshBeanFactory() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (!this.refreshed.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once");
        }
        this.beanFactory.setSerializationId(getId());
    }
```

Also it means it could be not possible to call refresh() manually even once - as already stated it depends on how application context is constructed. If no-argument constructor is used when creating instance of application context then refresh() should be possible to call afterwards (once), however if configuration file location (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) is specified in call of constructor or annotated configuration class (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) then refresh() is called inside the constructor so more refresh() calls are not possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the `refresh()` method because you are holding your context off the `GenericXmlApplicationContext`. You should really be holding it off `ApplicationContext` in which case `refresh()` wouldn't be exposed to you and rightfully so since it has to do with Spring Beans housekeeping and not your application code.

Same goes for `load()`, it wouldn't be visible to you either if you hold the `GenericXmlApplicationContext` object off an `ApplicationContext` reference.

What you are really trying to do is what the `GenericXmlApplicationContext` [constructor is doing](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/3.1.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/context/support/GenericXmlApplicationContext.java#GenericXmlApplicationContext.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29):

```
public  GenericXmlApplicationContext(String... resourceLocations) {
        load(resourceLocations);
        refresh();
}
```

So what you are after is:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("app-context-xml.xml");
```

To anwser your last question why calling `refresh()` twice throws an error I think the exception is quite specific:

```
GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once
```

Comment: My question is what exactly be done in load() and refresh() methods. What happens when i call load() on context and what happens when i call refresh() on context?

Comment: Please re-read your question, in your comment you are asking a different thing that needs to be a new question/questions. Also, please improve your approval rate on your prior questions.